# How to save prime number (1-100) in array and call the 2 prime randomly

Tags: java

How to save the prime number in my code to an array and call 2 random of them

**This is my edited code#3 which is suggested by @Stephen C**

```
public class prima {

public  static int[] getPrima(int aw, int ak) {
        int [] primes;
        int jmlPrim=0;

        int h = 0;
        primes = new int[5];

        boolean isPrima;
        for (int i = 2; i <= ak; i++) {
            isPrima = true;
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrima = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrima == true) {
                //System.out.print(i + " ");
                jmlPrim++;
                primes[jmlPrim]=i;

            }

        }
            /*here the code for random prime number*/
            final Random random = new Random();
        final int i1 = random.nextInt(primes[jmlPrim]);
        final int prime1 = primes[i1];
        System.out.println( "i1= " + i1);

        return null;

    }
public static void main(String[] args) {


     System.out.println(prima.getPrima(1, 10));

}

}
```

i want to save the result of prima.getPrima(1,100) in an array,

before i understanding what is the @Stephen C mean, i edit my code like above,

@Stephen C, please correct that..., how to check or ensure that my prime number stored in

```
primes[jmlPrim];
```

for addition, i add code to get random value from primes[jmlPrim];

```
final Random random = new Random();
            final int i1 = random.nextInt(primes[jmlPrim]);
            final int prime1 = primes[i1];
            System.out.println( "i1= " + i1);
```

**and this is i get when i run that code**

```
array= 2,array= 3,array= 5,array= 7,i1= 4
null
```

why i1=4?? as i know 4 isn't prime number

Comment: Please clarify -- what are you trying to do again? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Maybe use `java.util.ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: you want to store prime numbers in a String array? why? use Math.random() to generate a random number between 1 and 1000 and use it as your array index, or index of list. I am not very clear what the problem is.

Comment: @Jayz yes..., because the parameter is String[] args, correct me if i false..., i've done generating a random number between 1 and 100, but i've not yet get a solution to generating random value of prime number :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the nature of the Question, this is probably "a learning exercise" ... so I'm not going to provide code.

Here's a "first cut" for the "save the primes in array" part:

1. Change the method's return type to `int[]`.
2. Allocate an array of the appropriate size to hold the primes.
3. Add a variable that is the next position in the array to add a prime.
4. When you find a prime, add it like this:

   ```
    primes[index] = prime;
    index++;
   ```
5. Return the array

This is all basic "Java 101" stuff.  If you have difficulty understanding how to do it, review your lecture notes, your text book or the Oracle Java tutorial.

(Note that this doesn't deal with the issue that you don't know how many primes there are between `awal` and `akhir`.)

---

The second part of your question ... *"i have no idea how to call the 2 random of them"* ... is incomprehensible.  I'm not going to guess what you might mean.

Comment: i was edit my code above..., please correct me...

Comment: @adhit_yogapratama - writing and debugging the code your job :-)

Comment: But this part is definitely wrong: "int[] primes=null;".  Read your lecture notes (etc) on how to **ALLOCATE** an array.

Comment: value null actually given by eclipse, before i assign null value, i try this code int[] primes; int b= new int[prima.getPrima(1,100).length]; prime= new int[b]; it look strange..., and it was error. if i assign b=20, i'm not sure that in 1-100 there are 20 prime number, maybe i could be less or  more...:(

Comment: hi sir Stephen, i was modificate my code above..., please correct :-D, and how to check that my prime number was stored in primes[jmlPrim]; thanks... :)

Comment: *"if i assign b=20, i'm not sure that in 1-100 there are 20 prime number, maybe i could be less or more..."*.  That's right.  That's why putting them into an array is not such a good idea in the first place.  Look at the javadocs for `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

how to call the 2 random of them... (given an array 'primes')

```
final int n = primes.length;
final Random random = new Random();
final int i1 = random.nextInt(n);
int i2 = i1;
while (i2 == i1) {
    i2 = random.nextInt(n);
}
final int prime1 = primes[i1];
final int prime2 = primes[i2];
```

Comment: i try your code..., there is the result array= 2,array= 3,array= 5,array= 7,i1= 4
null
4 isn't prime number :(